# Fatal error in latex

Tags: xetex

Hi there I am using texstudio version 2.12.6. I tried compiling a document (CV) but it keeps repeating the fatal error : "cannot-use-pdftex" The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX to function. You must change your typesetting engine to, e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex" instead of plain "latex" or "pdflatex". For immediate help type H .
I tried to configured the default compiler from pdflatex to xelatex but it will not just work. It keeps returning to pdflatex when I go back to check.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: your question is just about the editor you are using, but you have not said which editor that is. On the command line, calling latex directly switching from pdflatex to xelatex simply means typing `xelatex file` instead of `pdflatex file`.

Answer (score 1):

You can either go to the `Tools -> Commands` menu and choose `xelatex`, like this:

[image]

Or, change the default compiler, go to the `Options -> Configure TeXstudio`, choose the `Build` icon and change the default in the editing window:

[image]

Comment: It wouldn't still work. The error provided is as stated below. Undefined control sequence. \begin{document}
Missing number, treated as zero. \begin{document}
Font \fb=''[cmr10]'' not loadable: metric data not found or bad.
XLTXTRA IS TO BE USED ONLY UNDER XETEX. LOAD FONTSPEC DIRECTLY, INSTEAD.

Comment: Did you click on OK after you've changed the default compiler?

Comment: Yes I did that.

Comment: Which distribution do you have, on which system?